# Jquery Show div on Clicking scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to hide a div if I click any where on page and not inside the div. But If i click on Scrollbar for that div, I am unable to stop div hiding. What might be the issue?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KbCN/3/)

Expectation: Do not hide div if I move scroll bar.***(In Internet explorer)***

```
    var $container = $(".toolbarContent");

//Hide red div if we click out side of the red div
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (!$container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $container.hide("slow");
        }
    });

$('#showDiv').click(function () {
$container.show();
});
```

Comment: What is the browser?,I've tested it in Google Chrome,and the div,was not hided while I've clicked the scroll bar.

Comment: I am trying with IE as it is the mandatory browser my company prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I'have tested your example in Chrome and Firefox,and there was no issues,But you have used jQuery 2.0 which is not supported by IE 8,may be that was the cause of the issue
[here is the browser support details for jQuery 2.0](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)